# MySQL magic column "name" and synthesized columns

Tags: mysql, sql-like

So I got a SQL statement. The idea is that I want to do a case-insensitive LIKE.
I do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  FilenameId AS id,
  LOWER(CONVERT(BINARY(Filename.Name) USING utf8)) AS name
  FROM Filename
  WHERE name LIKE '%something%'
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

This works fine, however my query also returns the case-transformed name. What I want to do
is synthesize the insensitive name and do a LIKE query on it, but also return the non case-transformed name.

```
SELECT 
  FilenameId AS id,
  Filename.Name AS name,
  LOWER(CONVERT(BINARY(Filename.Name) USING utf8)) AS iname
  FROM Filename
  WHERE iname LIKE '%something%'
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

...but then MySQL happily refuses:

```
  Unknown column 'iname' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am on MySQL 5.5 FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you came up with this, but usually others have trouble getting `LIKE` case sensitive, not the other way round.

Write your query simply like this:

```
SELECT 
FilenameId AS id,
Filename.Name AS name
FROM Filename
WHERE name LIKE '%something%'
```

And in general, you can't access aliases in WHERE clause. Either put your query into a subquery like Dhinakaran suggested or use `HAVING` (if you are lazy).

The difference? `WHERE` is rowbased, `HAVING` works on the result after applying `WHERE` clause (and `GROUP BY`).

From the **[manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)**:

> The following two statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC';
        -> 0
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason I have to do this lap dance is that I have to talk to a database that has been created without proper encoding configs in place. And I am rusty on my SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub query then put where on subquery

```
Select * from (SELECT 
  FilenameId AS id,
  Filename.Name AS name,
  LOWER(CONVERT(BINARY(Filename.Name) USING utf8)) AS iname
  FROM Filename ) temp
  WHERE temp.iname LIKE '%something%'
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Or

```
 SELECT 
  FilenameId AS id,
  Filename.Name AS name,
  AS iname
  FROM Filename
  WHERE LOWER(CONVERT(BINARY(Filename.Name) USING utf8))  LIKE '%something%'
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```